# Changing Earth?

Tags: climate, earth, weather

How would energy transfer, weather and climate be different if Earth had a different axial tilt? Different diameter? Different period of rotation? Different period of revolution? Would anything change?

Comment: Welcome, Maybe add by how much, as this is far too broad a question at the moment, how much more of  tilt, 2 degrees? 20 degrees?  how much bigger, how much longer, the potential answer changes drastically dependent on these factors

Comment: The answer is yes. Unless you asking for a recommendation to a specific physics textbook, you will need to pick a single question and be more specific regarding the amount of change.

Comment: Hi, Jennifer, welcome to Worldbuilding Stack Exchange. You really have four questions in one here, depending on what property of Earth you change. That's pretty broad, and considering that climate modeling in any situation is complicated, you definitely need to narrow this down a bit. Please [edit] your question to pick one of these changes, and explain in a bit more detail what changed. For instance, if you've changed the length of a day, what is Earth's new rotation period?

Answer (score 0):

**Very Basic Analysis**

**Size**

If the Earth was larger, then rain clouds would most likely be rarer at low levels, as the force of gravity would pull the water down, this would drastically depend on how much bigger

**Tilt**

if the Tilt was more pronounced it would not only make seasons slightly more erratic, but also the temperature range of the day more erratic as well. imagine a world when at night in the summer, home would be in Scandinavia, but in the day time it would be in central Africa. not that much of a deal in the summer, because of the residual heat of the day, however in the winter, when daytime was in Scandinavian so very little direct sunlight, so very cold, being out of the sun at an African area would mean just as much heat would be lost but less taken in, so very cold winters, again this would drastically depnd on how much more or less tilt

**Longer Day** (slower rotation)

If the days were longer then the sun would heat the planet that little bit more making it hotter, and more heat would be lost at night making it colder, again the temperature change would be more pronounced,

**Shorter Day** (faster rotation)

This would mean less heating time but also less cooling time, so the average tempearture would be lower but less of a shift

**Results**

and Temperature differentials is what drives the weather patterns around the world, hot air rises, cold air moves in to take its place and creates wind, so it would most likely be a far windier planet with high up concentrated clouds that would drop rain that would probably hurt on impact at least when it was warm enough to rain and not potentially just be ice, in the winter, and then arid deserts in the summer

I know this is very basic ideas, but hope it helps